# How can I get a popped tooltip at exactly where the click event happens?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to develop an app. Now, I want to popup a tooltip at where the click event happens. Just like the picture shows below. I just want the triangle appears at where I clicked.

[image]

Any idea is appreciated. THX

Comment: This picture doesn't show any bubbles?

Comment: Based on your picture, you're specifying a tooltip.

Comment: Write a directive and attach it to the "tooltipable" container. Bind click event, and on click use e.clientX/e.pageX, etc to position tooltip.

Comment: sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a small mix of JS, CSS, and HTML

```js
var button = document.getElementById('test-button');
var handleClick = function(e) {
  var existingTooltip = document.getElementById('popup-tooltip');
  if (existingTooltip) document.body.removeChild(existingTooltip);
  var buttonPosition = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    popup = document.createElement('div'),
    coords = {
      pageX: buttonPosition.left + (buttonPosition.width / 2),
      pageY: (buttonPosition.top - bodyRect.top) + (buttonPosition.height / 2)
    };

  popup.id = 'popup-tooltip';
  popup.classList.add('popup');
  document.body.appendChild(popup);
  popup.style.left = coords.pageX + 'px';
  popup.style.top = coords.pageY + 'px';
}

  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```css
button {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30px);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #666
}

.popup:before,
.popup:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -1px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.popup:after {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="test-button">Test</button>
```